# How can I active a specific worksheet based on a variable. The variable will have the name of the desired Sheet to activate

Tags: excel, vba

I need to activate a different Sheet on different times. 
The Sheet I will need to activate will vary based on a cell value (C2). 
Cell value (C2) in the Sheet named "Report" will contain the name of the Sheet.
Can't get to get it done ...

I am trying this, I read elsewhere:

```
Sheets(Sheets("Report").Range("C2")).Activate
```

I get:

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: Try `WorkSheets(WorkSheets("Report").Range("C2").Value).Activate`

Comment: Just out of interest, would you really need to activate sheets? It's generally a bad practice and can be avoided for most purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
WorkSheets(WorkSheets("Report").Range("C2").Value).Activate
```

**Working:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value).Activate
```

Your code would have work to if you added `.Value`

```
Sheets(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value).Activate
```

Comment: @vas.luis Why did you unnacept my answer :o